# Useing pyautogui how to append a value to the coordinates from "locateCenterOnScreen"

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui
I am looking for a point on my screen like that

```
start = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/Anton/Desktop/PYtik/Ablage_(driver)/Image01.png')
print(start)
```

When start is printed I get this: Point(x=1378, y=337)
Here my question how can I append a number x or y in the var start?
I already tried to split the var "start", but It is now working is there an easier way to change the x and y points of the start var?
Start is this for example
start = Point(x=1378, y=337)

Answer (score 1):

`pyautogui` uses `pyscreeze` to take screenshot. So the returned value from `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen` is the returned value of `pycreeze.locateCenterOnScreen`. This, we can see it [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/a62027c63fdeccfaaa0e8eda9e999cdea28a1a02/pyautogui/__init__.py#L207) in the source.

Now, the returned value of `pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen` is the returned value of `pyscreeze.center`, which is a `Point` (a namedtuple). We can see the definition of `Point` [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/0446e87235e0079f591f0c49ece7d487dedc2f9a/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L116).

Hence, an instance of `Point` is immutable. So, to add a certain offset to it, we have to create a new variable:

```py
start = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/Anton/Desktop/PYtik/Ablage_(driver)/Image01.png')
startWithOffset = (start.x + X_OFFSET, start.y + Y_OFFSET)
```

Comment: So how would it look with numbers? Just the second line. Doch In need to deine x?